# My function is returning a promise while trying to render an image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to render images using the TMDB api. In my database i have the IMDB id's. TMDB api has a method that return a poster_path(image) for a given IMDB id.
Here is my code:

```
const IMAGE_API="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";
const popular =(props)=> {

   async function imdbIdFind(imdb_id) {
       var result = await ApiService.findAll(imdb_id);
       console.log(result);
       return result.data.movie_results[0].poster_path;
   }
    return (

        props.popularMovies.map((movie, index) => {
            return (
                <Card style={{width: '18rem'}}>
                    <Card.Img variant="top" src={IMAGE_API + imdbIdFind(movie.movieId)}/>
                    <Card.Body>
                        <Card.Title>{movie.originalTitle}</Card.Title>
                    </Card.Body>
                </Card>
            )
        })

    )
}
export default  popular;
```

Here is the ApiService findAll method

```
const ApiService ={
    findAll:(id)=>
        axios
            .get(https://api.themoviedb.org/3/find/${id},{
                params:{
                    api_key:API_KEY,
                    external_source:"imdb_id"
                }
            })
```

The parent of the popular component is the home component:

```
render() {
            return(

        <div className={"row "}>
            <div className={"col-md-12"}>
                <h3 className={"upcoming-movies"}>Popular movies</h3>
            </div>
            <div className={"col-md-12"}>
                <PopularMovies  popularMovies={this.state.popularMovies}/>
            </div>
        </div>
            )}
```

The error i am getting is this :
**GET [https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/[object%20Promise]](https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/%5Bobject%20Promise%5D) 404**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

The components are rendered before the api call is resolved and the function returns a `Promise`, to get the value you need to use `then` block or `async/await`. It is not recommended to call async function from render.

#### Solution 1: Get all the paths

You can store the paths in the component state:

```
const [paths, setPath] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   const getPaths = async ()=> {
      const result = await Promise.all(props.popularMovies.map(movie => imdbIdFind(movie.movieId)));
      setPath(...result);
   }
   getPaths();
}, []);  

async function imdbIdFind(imdb_id) {
   var result = await ApiService.findAll(imdb_id);
   return result.data.movie_results[0].poster_path;
}
```

Then:

```
<Card.Img variant="top" src={IMAGE_API + paths[index]}/>
```

#### Solution 2: Create a component to render the image

You can store the path in the component state:

```
const CardImage = ({movieId, ...props}) => {

 const [path, setPath] = useState([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   imdbIdFind();
 }, []);  

 async function imdbIdFind() {
   var result = await ApiService.findAll(movieId);
   setPath(result.data.movie_results[0].poster_path);
 }
 
 return (<Card.Img src={IMAGE_API + path} {...props}/>)
}
```

Then render the CardImage component:

```
<Card style={{width: '18rem'}}>
    <CardImage variant="top" movie={movie}/>
...
</Card>
```

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined this error

Comment: Yes, that is because al the first render paths.length is equal 0, you need to check it before. Are you using something like this paths[index].property?

Comment: How can i check the paths.length?

Comment: Before check that result has the correct format

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution. I think the second one is more clear